# Android Studio use setOnTouchListener after changing layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

I like to swipe right, left to switch the layout of my Activity. But after switching the layout once the `setOnTouchListener` stop working. What is my fault?

My Activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static Fragment fragment;
private int pagenumber;
private ConstraintLayout cl;
    private View factory;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);


        cl = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        pagenumber= 0;


        cl.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {

            public void onSwipeRight() {
                if (pagenumber != 0)
                    pagenumber = pagenumber - 1;
                if(pagenumber==0){
                    setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);
                    factory = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.instruction_1, null);

                    cl = factory.findViewById(R.id.layout);
                }
              else if(pagenumber==1){
                    setContentView(R.layout.instruction_2);
                    factory = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.instruction_2, null);
                    cl = factory.findViewById(R.id.layout);
              }

            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                if(pagenumber<2) {
                    pagenumber = pagenumber + 1;


                     if (pagenumber==1){
                         setContentView(R.layout.instruction_2);
                         factory = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.instruction_2, null);
                         cl = factory.findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    }
                    else if (pagenumber==2){
                         setContentView(R.layout.instruction_3);
                         factory = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.instruction_3, null);
                         cl = factory.findViewById(R.id.layout);
                    }
                }

            }


        });

    }
}
```

Comment: because you are changing the whole layout with `setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);`

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Makarand i want to archiev to change the layout of the activity with a swipe. Like a book

Comment: do you have only 3 pages?

Comment: @Makarand Yes just 3

Answer (score 0):

Why the app is not working after first swipe is bcz when you swipe once you are replacing the layout file with another when you still have reference to old Constrained layout which is no more now.

You are trying to implement the behavior of **Fragments**

You should not be replacing the layout file completely, instead create a Layout inside the xml file and replace it Or just use **ViewPager**.

I think you are looking for something like this.
Try it

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static Fragment fragment;
private int pagenumber;
private ConstraintLayout cl;
private View factory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);


    cl = findViewById(R.id.layout);
    pagenumber = 0;


    cl.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {

        public void onSwipeRight() {
            if (pagenumber == 0) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);
                pagenumber = 1;
            } else if (pagenumber == 1) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_2);
                pagenumber = 2;
            } else if (pagenumber == 2) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_3);
                pagenumber = 3;
            }
        }

        public void onSwipeLeft() {
           if (pagenumber == 1) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_0);
                pagenumber = 0;
            } else if (pagenumber == 2) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_1);
                pagenumber = 1;
            }else if (pagenumber == 3) {
                setContentView(R.layout.instruction_2);
                pagenumber = 2;
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```